# Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, but 2 were specified

Tags: algorithm, swift2, xcode7.2

I'm trying to get this algorithm working with swift 2.1: http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~wkliao/Kmeans/

though I am getting the error on this line:

```
  return map(Zip2Sequence(centroids, clusterSizes)) { Cluster(centroid: $0, size: $1) }
```

Here's the full function:

```
func kmeans<T : ClusteredType>(
        points: [T],
        k: Int,
        seed: UInt32,
        distance: ((T, T) -> Float),
        threshold: Float = 0.0001
    ) -> [Cluster<T>] {

    let n = points.count
    assert(k <= n, "k cannot be larger than the total number of points")

    var centroids = points.randomValues(seed, num: k)
    var memberships = [Int](count: n, repeatedValue: -1)
    var clusterSizes = [Int](count: k, repeatedValue: 0)

    var error: Float = 0
    var previousError: Float = 0

        repeat {
            error = 0
            var newCentroids = [T](count: k, repeatedValue: T.identity)
            var newClusterSizes = [Int](count: k, repeatedValue: 0)

            for i in 0..<n {
                let point = points[i]
                let clusterIndex = findNearestCluster(point, centroids: centroids, k: k, distance: distance)
                if memberships[i] != clusterIndex {
                    error += 1
                    memberships[i] = clusterIndex
                }
                newClusterSizes[clusterIndex]++
                newCentroids[clusterIndex] = newCentroids[clusterIndex] + point
            }
            for i in 0..<k {
                let size = newClusterSizes[i]
                if size > 0 {
                    centroids[i] = newCentroids[i] / size
                }
            }

            clusterSizes = newClusterSizes
            previousError = error
        } while abs(error - previousError) > threshold

        return map(Zip2Sequence(centroids, clusterSizes)) { Cluster(centroid: $0, size: $1) }
}
```

How would I change this to remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to to the following:

```
return (0..<k).map { Cluster(centroid: centroids[$0], size: clusterSizes[$0]) }
```

From the **Swift**'s `Zip2Sequence<Sequence1, Sequence2>` documentation:

> A sequence of pairs built out of two underlying sequences, where the
>   elements of the `i`th pair are the `i`th elements of each underlying
>   sequence.

`Zip2Sequence<[T], [Int]>` generator's element is `(T, Int)` tuple.
You can access the individual elements of this tuple by their index.

So, the following code should work for you:

```
return Zip2Sequence(centroids, clusterSizes).map { Cluster(centroid: $0.0, size: $0.1) }
```